# How to test action props from ReactiveDict inside React component with Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, reactjs, enzyme, mantrajs

I am working on an app that uses `ReactiveDict`. My project is built with Meteor, with Mantra specification.

I have a React Component named `Login`. The concept is, when the component renders, the `ReactiveDict` state is cleared, since there is no error upon component rendering. That is fine though. I have this code in my container:

```
export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  context: () => context,
  loginUser:actions.login.loginUser,
  clearState: actions.globals.clearState
});
```

These are the actions that the component will perform. In my component:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.clearState('LOGIN_ERROR_MESSAGE');
}
```

Lastly, in my test code, I have:

```
it.only('should render a <Form/> component', () => {
   const loginWrapper = shallow(<Login/>);
   expect(loginWrapper.find(Form)).to.have.length(1);
 });
```

When I run `npm test`, it says, `this.props.clearState` is not a function. How can I fix this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think is more convenient to clear the error on unmount? ReactiveDict is not persistent anyways, so - clearing state on unmount - if you refresh the page or unmount the component, the error would be cleared already. So there's no reason to clear the state before mounting. Typically you would do something like this in mantrajs:

```
export const composer = ({context, clearState}, onData) => {
  const {LocalState} = context();
  const error = LocalState.get('LOGIN_ERROR_MESSAGE');
  onData(null, {error});

  // return the function that clears the state and the state gets reset on unmount
  return clearState;
};

export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  context: () => context,
  loginUser: actions.login.loginUser,
  clearState: actions.globals.clearState
});

export default composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composer),
  useDeps(depsMapper)
)(Login);
```